# Let MVC Website start Process as Administrator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, process, administrator, lync-2010

I have a MVC Site that should start a Process that does a Lync call under certain circumstances. Everything works fine if I start it manually and on my development machine with VS2012 it works too. But on IIS7 on our Windows 2008 Server if it gets called by the website it doesn't work. My .exe file starts but it crashes on LyncClient.GetClient().

Any ideas how to work around that problem? I thought it might be possible to run the App via C# code as the Administrator Account instead of System.

Answer (score 0):

As noone commented here I post how I solved the problem. As we host the server I just said via Registry that the console "Administrator" account should log on automatically. In the autostart folder of that User I've put my tool and changed it a bit. The tool now checks every view seconds if a "startCall.txt" file exists and if yes it starts the call. The website just deletes or creates that file. In that way I can control the tool even if it is in a totally different user context (which seemed to be the problem).

I know it's a more or less cheap workaround but time wasn't my friend ;-)